# How would I model my NoSQL database for a conversational bot

Tags: database, api, nosql, aws

I'm currently developing a chatbot that will be used for booking trips. The particular party I'm interested in for now is the rider. I'm using AWS's DynamoDB, because it seemed to be the most flexible and fast for a system like this that is likely to get lots of concurrent traffic, and in which records won't have well-defined schemas.

The idea is, the rider greets the bot, the bot responds asking them if they're a rider or driver. For now, I'm only concerned about the rider. The first and most obvious thing is to create an item in the DB of the user, identified by the phone number of the user. in addition to that, I should also probably store the role of the user as an attribute, so that in the future they don't have to repeat this first step.

From here, the rider then has the option to view active trips (ones that have been booked but not completed), cancel a trip, or book a new trip. The trip details will all be stored on a different database I handle elsewhere. The only thing that I will store concerning the trip in the message history database is the trip's id, so that I can retrieve the relevant details of the trip from the other database using the id.

The next steps in the flow should be straightforward.

Here's my problem. I have to track context to know where in the flow the user is. How I'm thinking of doing this is by creating a conversation item in the database that then tracks the context/topic with a user. Then, when the user enters into a new part of the flow, the context for that conversation is updated, and the chatbot knows what response to then give.

From what I read in the AWS docs, they recommended that you use a single-table design for this. But I'm struggling to understand how exactly I would structure the database in this case, and particularly in an efficient manner. Would I set the partition key to be the user_id (phone number), and then store lists of messages and conversations associated with that number?

I'd appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: I suggest you use an integer key for your user primary key. Using the phone number means the user becomes a new user should they change their phone number. History is lost.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between relational databases and the different kinds of NoSQL databases. First, decide how you want to model your data and choose a database based on **that**. There is also a good chance that what you call "lots of concurrent traffic" is much less than what AWS calls "lots of concurrent traffic"

Comment: @kiwiron Was thinking the same. Just not sure how to receive a notification that a user has changed their number. I'll figure that out later I suppose

Comment: @AlePouroullis You should always have a unique id number that has no other meaning. Even if you use  a unique identifier that has some meaning like phone number. The point is your unique meaningless ID never has a reason to change. With that you can associate as many phone numbers with then as you like.

Comment: @candied_orange appreciate the advice. I ended up making two items: one for a user, and one for a phone number. The phone number has a user id attribute. The user id is then used to access all the user's information as opposed to a phone number. I'm not going to handle a change of phone numbers for now, but the idea is to persist a user's data across phone numbers. I'm not sure if the way I've done it is inefficient because it involves two queries (one to find the phone number record which contains the user id, and another to access the user using the id), but it should serve for now.